# Plotting var A (x axis) against var B (y axis) by printing a function of var A, f(A), on the x axis

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot two variables (let's say A and B) against each other, however instead of displaying the values of A on the x-axis I would like to display exp(A).

What I want to do is different than simply plotting exp(A) against B, in the sense that the intervals of x-axis should still be determined with respect to A.

A simple example for my problem:

```
height <- c(176, 154, 138, 196, 132, 176, 181, 169, 150, 175)
bodymass <- c(82, 49, 53, 112, 47, 69, 77, 71, 62, 78)
plot(bodymass, height)
```

[image]

Instead of having the numbers 50, 60, ..., 110 on the x axis, I want to see exp(50), exp(60),...,exp(110) in the same exact spots (hence, the gap between values on the x-axis will not be proportional to the differences between displayed numbers).

If that is not possible, some other method to display these exponential values together with the regular ones would also be helpful.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: So just change labels or the `exp` affects the nature of the graph?!

Comment: I don't know how to change it without affecting the nature of the graph... That's exactly what I am asking

Comment: It's unclear to me. If you just want to change labels, that's "easy". But if the labels are changing due to changing the values by getting their `exp`, then that's different. It's confusing because: `What I want to do is different than simply plotting exp(A) against B`

Comment: As far as I see, the only way to display exp(A) on the x-axis is to plot with the code `plot(exp(A), B)`. However, then I obtain the plot of B against exp(A), which is different than the plot of B against A (the plot that I want to see). What I am actually trying to do is to plot a variable against log(income). I like this plot better because it is much smoother than plotting with income itself. But then when I look at the plot, I have to calculate income levels in my head by looking at the log values on x-axis. The graphs are not easy to read. I want to see income levels directly instead.